# Solve $6^x=36\cdot (9.75)^{x-2}$

Tags: functions

I try to solve the following equation:

$6^x=36\cdot (9.75)^{x-2}$

I tried:

$1=6\cdot (9.75)^{x-2}$

But this is obviously wrong!

I think it would be smarter to bring the whole expression on one side. How should I proceed instead?

Comment: Try $\log$ on both sides

Comment: Have you $6^x=36.9,75^{x-2}$ or this equation: $6^x=36.9.75^{x-2}$?

Comment: Hint: rewrite it as $\,(6/9.75)^{x-2} = 1.\ \ $

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Taking log

> $x\log 6 = \log 36 + (x-2)\log9.75$
>
> $x(\log6 - \log9.75) = \log36 - 2\log9.75$
>
> $x = \frac{\log36 - 2\log9.75}{\log6 - \log9.75}$
>
> $x = 2\frac{\log6 - \log9.75}{\log6 - \log9.75}$
>
> $x = 2$

Answer (score 14):

Divide each side by $36$ to get $6^{x-2}=9.75^{x-2}$. Hence $x=2$.

Answer (score 2):

$$6^x=36\cdot9.75^{x-2}6^x=6^2(9+3/4)^{x-2}$$
$$6^{x-2}=(39/4)^{x-2}$$
$$\left(\frac{6}{39/4}\right)^{x-2}=1$$
$$\left(\frac{24}{39}\right)^{x-2}=\left(\frac{24}{39}\right)^0$$
$$x-2=0$$
$$x=2$$